# Как поставить лимит на вывод одинаковых объектов в списке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, случайные-числа

Написал код с модулем *tkinter* для вывода 50 квадратов с разными цветами, а именно: красный, желтый, синий и зеленый. 
Но надо сделать так чтобы не выводило **`3 одинаковых цветов подряд`**, то есть поставить лимит на максимальное количество одинаковых объектов. 
Помогите пожалуйста, прикреплю мой код снизу.

```
import random
from tkinter import *

colors = ['#008000', '#FF0000', '#000080', '#FFFF00']

labelColors = []


def call_generators():

    for x in range(50):
        color = random.choice(colors)
        labelColors[x]['bg'] = color

    if colors


root = Tk()

root.title('Генератор')

root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(root.winfo_screenwidth(),root.winfo_screenheight()))

root.resizable(0, 0)


cordX = 60
cordY = 120
loopY = 1

for x in range(50):
    labelColor = Label(root, bg='white', borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
    labelColor.place(x=cordX, y=cordY, anchor=S, width=100, height=100)
    labelColors.append(labelColor)
    cordX = cordX + 120
    loopY = loopY + 1
    if loopY > 10:
        cordY = cordY + 120
        cordX = 60
        loopY = 1;

btnGenerate = Button(root, text='Сгенерировать', font='Arial 13 bold', borderwidth=4, command=call_generators)

btnGenerate.place(x=30, y=670, anchor=SW, width=300, height=50)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ну, можно смотреть, что два предыдущих цвета одинаковые и исключать из выбора этот одинаковый цвет. Я бы код написал, но в вашей концепции всё как-то сложновато выглядит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import random
from tkinter import *

colors = ['#008000', '#FF0000', '#000080', '#FFFF00']
labelColors = []


def call_generators():
    x = 0
#    for x in range(50):
    while x < 50:
        color = random.choice(colors)
        if x > 1:
            if labelColors[x-1]['bg'] != color or labelColors[x-2]['bg'] != color:
                labelColors[x]['bg'] = color
                x += 1
        else:      
            labelColors[x]['bg'] = color
            x += 1    

root = Tk()
root.title('Генератор')
root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(root.winfo_screenwidth(),root.winfo_screenheight()))
root.resizable(0, 0)

cordX = 60
cordY = 120
loopY = 1

for x in range(50):
    labelColor = Label(root, bg='white', borderwidth=2, relief="solid")
    labelColor.place(x=cordX, y=cordY, anchor=S, width=100, height=100)
    labelColors.append(labelColor)
    cordX = cordX + 120
    loopY = loopY + 1
    if loopY > 10:
        cordY = cordY + 120
        cordX = 60
        loopY = 1;

btnGenerate = Button(root, 
    text='Сгенерировать', 
    font='Arial 13 bold', 
    borderwidth=4, 
    command=call_generators
)
btnGenerate.place(x=30, y=670, anchor=SW, width=300, height=50)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]